# Тире со словом "это"

Tags: запятые, тире

Вот три варианта. Хотелось бы уточнить, как правильно пишется?

1. Как минимум, это - некрасиво.
2. Это, как минимум - некрасиво.
3. Это - некрасиво, как минимум

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире не нужно ни в каком варианте, примеры употребления можно найти на многих форумах учебных, например студворк. Очень подробно могут ответить и объяснить, в чем именно ошибка или какое работает правило.

1. Как минимум, это некрасиво.
2. Это, как минимум, некрасиво.
3. Это некрасиво, как минимум.